# Rest API Add item to sharepoint list - Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.String'. See the inner exception for more details

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, 2016, error

I have this Rest API to add an item to a SharePoint list in SP 2016 on premise.

I am passing information to it from global variables that get set in other APIs. The error I'm getting is:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.String'. See the inner exception for more details.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.String'. See the inner exception for more details."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

Any ideas on what I need to fix to get it to add items to the list?

```
function logHistory(filename){
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('NewAccountsDeletedAttachmentsLog')/items";
var DATA = JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.NewAccountsDeletedAttachmentsLogListItem' }, 'Title': acctnum, 'ParentID':parentitem, 'Filename':filename, 'AccountNumber':acctnum });
console.log("In logHistory Function:");
console.log(DATA);
console.log(DATA.length);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: DATA,
        headers:{
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        }
    })
.done(function(data){
    // Code when request was successful
    alert("Successful");

.fail(function(error){
    // Code when request failed
    alert("Failed");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
})
}
```

Comment: What is the data/column type of `AccountNumber` & `ParentID` columns? If column type is single line of text, you have to pass the string value in `data`.

Comment: They're all single line of text.

Comment: how do I pass the string value???? how is that line formed?

Comment: Which variables hold the number values, `acctnum`, `parentitem`? Check my answer given below and convert the number variable to string accordingly wherever required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are passing "Number" value to some of the columns which expects "String" value.

You can convert the number to string before passing it into `data` like:

```
String(12345);

//with variable
String(acctnum);
```

So, final data object will be like:

```
var DATA = JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.NewAccountsDeletedAttachmentsLogListItem' },
                'Title': String(acctnum),
                'ParentID': parentitem,
                'Filename': filename,
                'AccountNumber': String(acctnum)
            });
```

Comment: Yes.  This fixed it.  Thank you so much!  It's working now.